# My template file not showing header and footer

Tags: module, magento-1, template

I want to add a new landing page between cart and checkout page of Magento. I succeeded in adding a new phtml file with the help of controller function.

```
public function linkAction() { 
   echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('vatexempt/checkou‌​t/onepage/vatexempt.phtml')->toHtml(); 
}
```

But I am facing a weird issue, I am not getting header and footer in this template file.

Comment: Please add the layout xml file you are using for this page.

Comment: @Sander I am calling it with the controller function on click event.

Comment: How you call it is not the point :) please add the layout XML file where the header and footer are included and perhaps paste the contents of your controller file

Comment: this is the content of my controller filepublic function linkAction()
 {
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('vatexempt/checkout/onepage/vatexempt.phtml')->toHtml();
 }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By inserting a block via the controller you are not using the full power of templating in Magento. In you module add a layout xml to accomplish this.

your modules `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    [...]
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <helloworld>
                <file>vatexempt.xml</file>
            </helloworld>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    [...]
</frontend>
```

and in your controller file

```
public function linkAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

the layout file `design/frontend/[package]/[template]/layout/vatexempt.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <vatexempt_index_link> <!-- frontendname_controllername_actionname -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="vatexempt" template="vatexempt/checkou‌​t/onepage/vatexempt.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </vatexempt_index_link>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the content is called above header of magento how can this be solved?

Comment: sounds like your template is build up the wrong way. `content` should be displayed below the header

Comment: its default magento template

Comment: I would advice to post a new question with the contents of your layout XML etc since this is another issue than this question.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/40322/my-magento-page-shows-content-above-the-header please help on this