# My Magento page shows content above the header

Tags: template

I have added a new template file between cart page and checkout.The issue I am facing is that the content of the file is shown above the header please help me to solve this issue

```
public function linkAction()
{
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('vatexempt/checkout/onepage/vatexempt.phtml')->toHtml();
}
```

This is how I call the template file in my controller.

Following is the code in my xmo file

```
<vatexempt_index_link> <!-- frontendname_controllername_actionname -->
    <reference name="content">
       <block type="core/template" name="vatexempt" template="vatexempt/checkou‌​t/onepage/vatexempt.phtml" />
    </reference>
</vatexempt_index_link>
```

Please Help me I am using magento 1.8 default theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this change in layout.xml

```
<vatexempt_link_link translate="label">
    <label>link</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
           <block type="core/template" name="vatexempt" template="vatexempt/vatexempt.phtml" />
    </reference>
    </vatexempt_link_link>
```

and set controller function as

```
public function linkAction()
{
$this->loadLayout();
$this->renderLayout();
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that there is output before the header is because you use:

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('vatexempt/checkout/onepage/vatexempt.phtml')->toHtml();
```

You should change this to the following so that the content is added to the content section of your page:

```
$this->loadLayout()
            ->_addContent(
                $this->getLayout()
                    ->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('vatexempt/checkout/onepage/vatexempt.phtml')->toHtml()
            )
            ->renderLayout();
```

Comment: I am getting following error Call to undefined method Indies_Vatexempt_LinkController::_addContent() in C:\wamp\www\vat\app\code\local\Indies\Vatexempt\controllers\LinkController.php on line 19